# preg_match / php style regex to find repeating alphanumeric characters, comma delimited?

Tags: regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to figure out a preg_match / php style regex to find repeating groups of alphanumeric characters(of any length), separated by commas?

so if I have string "c,b,a,xz,x,b,a,c,xz,x,x,b,a"

would return the first series of letters that repeat more than two values. I think I need to do a recursive backreference, maybe something like

```
<?php
    // lines removed for simplicity
    // test string = "c,b,a,xz,x,b,a,c,xz,x,x,b,a"
    $haystack = "c,b,a,xz,x,b,a,c,xz,x,x,b,a";
    $answer = preg_match('/([A-z]{2,*}[\s]{1})([A-z \s]*)[\1]*/', $haystack );

    echo $answer; // print the first occurrence of the repeating series of two or more
?>
```

I just need to find and echo out the first occurrence of a repeating series of two or more values. Is there a way to use a backreference recursively, or some better method?

edit: code vomit removed.

Comment: `$haystack` is a string.  `implode` concatenates all the array values into a string.

Comment: **Warning: `[A-z]` is an error.  Do not use `[A-z]`.**  If you want to match any upper- or lowercase ASCII letter, use `[A-Za-z]`, or set the case-insensitive/ignore-case flag and use `[A-Z]` or `[a-z]`.

Comment: @Alan: You're right if we assume the string can contain any chars besides letters and commas.  Commas aren't in `[A-z]`, though, so it's not an issue unless there are requirements we haven't been told about.

Comment: Hmmm.  @609south, is that what happened?  Did you use `[A-z]` knowing it would match more than just letters, but that it would be okay this time because `,` isn't one of the extra characters it matches?  Or did you see someone else use it and assume it was okay because nobody pointed it out as an error? ;)

Comment: @AlanMoore: I originally wrote it to do the same against letters + whitespace, and had tried just using \w (instead of [A-z] or [A-Za-z], so the code above is still showing remnants of the old version. Apologies if this was confusing.

Comment: @AlanMoore: You caught me. I didn't want someone to hand me the answer to the actual problem I needed to solve, just get me in the right direction. The original list was a series of numbers separated by whitespace. I converted it over to letters and commas so I would at least have to figure out some part of it myself, and I apparently missed some details. Good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'/\b(\w+,\w+),(?:.*,)?\1\b/'` should work.  It'd match any sequence of two items, any amount of other stuff, and then the same sequence again.

Catch is, it will likely find the first sequence that has a duplicate, not the sequence that has the first duplicate, due to how regexes work.  (The match that starts earliest, wins.)  For example, if you have `'a,b,c,d,c,d,a,b,c'`, `$matches[1]` would probably be `'a,b'`, even though `'c,d'` would match earlier.

To find the first duplicate, you'd have to be able to match that and have a backreference to it in a lookbehind assertion.  If that's even legal (which i doubt it is), it'd have to be fixed width before PHP would let it happen.

**Edit:**
Although, now that i think about it...if you *reversed the string* and then used `'/.*\b(\w+,\w+),(?:.*?,)??\1\b/'` on that, it might work.  That dances around the constraint i'd mentioned; with the string reversed, the duplicate comes *before* the original, so now we can match the duplicate and then refer to it "later".

The `.*` at the beginning of the expression grabs as much as it can, so the match will start as close to the end of the reversed string (and therefore, as close to the *beginning* of the original string) as possible.  And the extra `?`s make their corresponding bits lazy, so they match as little as necessary.  Of course, once you find the match in the reversed string, you'll need to reverse it in order to get the match in the original string.

And of course, this could break all to hell in the presence of UTF-8.  (Then again, most regexes would.)  If you're just dealing with ASCII, though, it should work.

Comment: A comma doesn't count as an item. I will give this a go, though. Thanks.

Comment: A comma doesn't count as an item, no.  But the `.*` in the first group would have to match at least one letter (assuming two commas in a row is invalid), so there'd have to be at least two items in the group.  Although now that i think about it...all you really have to match is a pair.  Lemme simplify.

Answer (score 1):

Not a PHP expert, but I would think you could use this regex
`~\b([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})\b(?=.*\b\1\b)~` in a while loop.

In the body, you could track the results in a hash array (if php has that),
to print out unique series and positions. Capture buffer 1 has the series.